# Eliminate Java Popup Box On Shopify Site

Tags: java, shopify

I am trying to solve a little issue I am having that causes a bit of annoyance with users on our website.

What happens is when you click this link - [Configured Product](https://diamondbackcovers.com/products/diamondback-hd-chevy?variant=40790782473) we are getting a quick popup box that appears when you click the "RESET" link to go back to the previous page which would be the product master page to re-select a cover. It doesn't always appear, so if you refresh the page and keep trying you will eventually see it.

The box is identical to that of our master page which is the result you get when you click reset, or [this link](https://diamondbackcovers.com/products/diamondbackhd).

We are baffled as to what is making that java popup box appear and what we can do to stop it from coming up. It appears it is the feather-light box that is continuously showing up with the 'block' display. We would obviously want that to be 'none' so it does not appear. I know I might not have provided enough information to help solve this issue but if anybody could provide some insight or possible some assistance as to how we can fix this it would be appreciated.

Comment: Which one of the many popups I encountered looking at one page of your site was the Java popup?

Comment: Its when you click the reset box on a configured cover. It shows as black for a milli second and its the configuration box to pick a truck cover.